# How to determine why Spring @Controller is not getting requests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having trouble getting requests routed to one of my Spring @Controller that use @RequestMapping it is usually caused by a typo on my part but it is still annoying to hunt down those typos when you have a lot of controllers like I do.

for example a URI like /abc/{id}/something/{anotherId}

Is there some way to get spring to print out the process it used to determine that there was no match? In particular what would be useful is to know how far down the URI path there was a match as that would make finding typos a lot easier.

What debug flags exist for troubleshooting routing problems?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that you can do -

1. Increase the log level - to DEBUG or may be even TRACE, this will clearly show how Spring MVC is trying to match your request to a handler method.
2. Debug - you can put a breakpoint as early as the DispatcherServlet and see how the mapping is being resolved.
3. You can implement a Endpoint Documentation Controller - something along these lines - http://biju-allandsundry.blogspot.com/2012/03/endpoint-documentation-controller-for.html, which can show all the endpoints URI's supported in the application.

Comment: What categories do I put the DEBUG on I have tried org.springframework.web and org.springframework.http and still don't get what candidates were considered, I am interested in what was rejected and why rather than what was matched.